# CSS: link is "onClick" underlined (FireFox)

Tags: css, firefox, hyperlink

I'm, styling a hyperlink which has an own class.

```
.myLink
{
  display:block;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  margin: 0px 6px;
}

.myLink:hover
{
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  margin: 0px 6px;
  color:#000;
}
```

For the removing, I have this:

```
.myLink, .myLink:active, .myLink:visited
{
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

In IE everything is working fine, **but in Firefox my link gets underlined WHILE clicking on it**.
I thought, if I definde the ":active" part, it's going to work, but it isn't.
Help please.

Comment: I didn't found any underline in firefox. would you please give the working link.

Comment: When i try your styling theres no underlining.

Comment: .myLink a { text-decoration:none; } Did you try to use this?

Comment: @Oyeme Please read the question properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds less like a CSS issue but more like browser preferences/overrides. I'd try to add `!important` to the `text-decoration` attribute, but actually looking for the reason would be the even better solution. Best solution would be checking the origin of the style using a tool (IE's developer tools or Firefox' Firebug).

Comment: What's `!override`? Do you mean `!important`?

Comment: I hope it's the second part of this answer that you're accepting… If rather than trying to track down the cause of the issue you use `!important` instead, you'll potentially tie yourself in knots. It should really be used sparingly and as a last resort, as it will remove the **C** from **CSS**, taking a lot of power away from you.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a CMS or something with pre defined CSS files, it might be a browser specific CSS file causing this, as they will override the main CSS file. Even if you are not using a CMS or something with browser specific CSS files try Firebug in Firefox, this will tell you where in the CSS file the style is coming from and what CSS file is generating it.

www.getfirebug.com

Answer (score 0):

Either use !important or make sure your ".myLink, .myLink:active, .myLink:visited" rules are below in order